# Finding leaking memory?

Tags: java, memory

I have a system running a Java program and I believe it or something else is leaking memory. When the program is monitor for its memory use it de-allocates the memory as it is suppose to. But after a day or two the system ram is full and Kernel kills the process.

Are there any tools I can use in Linux to monitor memory Linux and find the leak or force clearing of memory? Free only seems to show me info.

Comment: Duplicate question on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143791/how-do-i-find-which-process-is-leaking-memory

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!